# Different Cell size in a collection view in ios

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

i already display the image as grid view using UICollectionView with equal size like follows
[image]

Next step i want to display cell as different size but the images fit into the that cell like this
[image] 
this need to be work in the storyboard because other functions done in the storyboard so somebody help me..

Answer (score 1):

In your collection view controller add:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView 
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout 
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   //return the size of the cell based on image size or other criteria
}
```

Add constraints to the image:

[image]

Comment: it changes only the cell size only,the images not fit that and the line space is also different

Comment: You should also set the view mode of the image to Aspect Fill

Comment: thank you it works but the line and the cell space is not like that screen shot(second)

Comment: i need to display the images grid view like the second screen shot,i use the above function as you said the images are fit into the cell but the line and the cell space are not equal(it not align properly) the images are display here and there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64501/discussion-between-prabakaran-and-user623396).