# CollectionView layout for different image orientation and aspect ratio?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, uicollectionview

I wonder how do we use a collectionview to display images with different sizes, aspect ratio and orientation? Is there a way to find a "match" within those image.

Take a look at this screenshot of DeviantArt iOS app:

[image]

You may have noticed that the images with the same height and could be fitted in the screen were in the same row, even though they have different orientation..

How is this possible thru SWIFT?

Please help me.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different Cell size in a collection view in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26802436/different-cell-size-in-a-collection-view-in-ios)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only one I know which has similar layout you show is [NHBalancedFlowLayout](https://github.com/njdehoog/NHBalancedFlowLayout). It is built in Objective-C, but you can have a look and write your own one or just use bridging header (description on how to use ObjC + Swift is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)).

**Update:**
After small research I have found one more great layout - [YJZAlbumCollectionViewLayout](https://github.com/johnny0614/YJZAlbumCollectionViewLayout). I would say, that this one looks even better. Also built in Objective-C.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! I hope others who have experienced doing similar stuff will share their answers too! :)