# UICollectionViewCell resizing in an image array

Tags: ios, swift, image, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hi I have an image array which consists of images with different sizes. I am going to display them in a Horizontal UICollectionView. And I need to show these images with same height , same padding (not the cell interim space, but the look of the image) and different widths.

Example:

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CollectionView layout for different image orientation and aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241782/collectionview-layout-for-different-image-orientation-and-aspect-ratio)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this method , inside it generate your random width and pass it to the width parameter

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
                  layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
           sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width:<#variableWidth#>,height:<#sameHeight#>)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well creating your custom collectionViewLayout is also an option. It will give you more flexibility but at the same time you have to do all the calculations yourself.

Looking at your case, it appears you can use a horizontal stack view embedded inside a scroll view. So in this approach you just need to add your views with different widths and set the stack view fill property to proportional. You can refer this [link](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/scrolling-stack-views/) for more details.